# The xacro files don't seem to work with each other. (ubuntu 20.04 noetic) R

Tags: ros, xacro

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, everyone!

An error occurred while configuring the robot arm as an xacro file.
The current simple model looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>

<robot name="manipulator" xmlns:xacro="http://www.ros.org/wiki/xacro">

   <!-- Begin include -->
   <xacro:include filename="$(find manipulator_description)/urdf/links_joints.xacro" />
   <!-- END include -->
   
   <!--Begin robot description -->
   <link_n_box name="base_link"
               origin_rpy="0 0 0" origin_xyz="0 0 0"
               size="1 1 1" />
       
   <joint name="joint_01" type="revolute">
    <axis xyz="0 1 0"/>
    <limit effort="1000.0" lower="-3.14" upper="3.14" velocity="0.5"/>
    <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0.5"/>
    <parent link="base_link"/>
    <child link="link_01"/>    
  </joint>  

   <link name="link_01">
         <visual>
           <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0.2" />
           <geometry>
               <cylinder radius="0.35" length="0.4"/>
           </geometry>
         </visual>
   </link>

  <joint name="joint_02" type="revolute">
    <axis xyz="0 1 0"/>
    <limit effort="1000.0" lower="-3.14" upper="3.14" velocity="0.5"/>
    <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0.4"/>
    <parent link="link_01"/>
    <child link="link_02"/>    
  </joint>   

   <link name="link_02">
         <visual>
           <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0.4" />
           <geometry>
               <cylinder radius="0.15" length="0.8"/>
           </geometry>
         </visual>
   </link>   
   
  <joint name="joint_03" type="revolute">
    <axis xyz="0 1 0"/>
    <limit effort="1000.0" lower="-3.14" upper="3.14" velocity="0.5"/>
    <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0.8"/>
    <parent link="link_02"/>
    <child link="link_03"/>    
  </joint>   

   <link name="link_03">
         <visual>
           <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0.4" />
           <geometry>
               <cylinder radius="0.15" length="0.8"/>
           </geometry>
         </visual>
   </link> 

  <joint name="joint_04" type="revolute">
    <axis xyz="0 1 0"/>
    <limit effort="1000.0" lower="-3.14" upper="3.14" velocity="0.5"/>
    <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0.8"/>
    <parent link="link_03"/>
    <child link="link_04"/>    
  </joint>   

   <link name="link_04">
         <visual>
           <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0.4" />
           <geometry>
               <cylinder radius="0.15" length="0.8"/>
           </geometry>
         </visual>
   </link>
   
  <joint name="joint_05" type="revolute">
    <axis xyz="0 0 1"/>
    <limit effort="1000.0" lower="-3.14" upper="3.14" velocity="0.5"/>
    <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0.8"/>
    <parent link="link_04"/>
    <child link="link_05"/>    
      </joint>
    
       <link name="link_05">
             <visual>
               <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0.125" />
               <geometry>
                   <cylinder radius="0.15" length="0.25"/>
               </geometry>
             </visual>
       </link>
       <!--END robot description -->
       
    </robot>
```

The macro files to be linked are as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<robot name="manipulator" xmlns:xacro="http://www.ros.org/wiki/xacro">

  <xacro:macro name="link_n_box" params="name origin_rpy origin_xyz size">
    <link name="${name}">
          <visual>
            <origin rpy="${origin_rpy}" xyz="${origin_xyz}" />
            <geometry>
                <box size="${size}" />
            </geometry>
          </visual>
    </link>
  </xacro:macro>

  <xacro:macro name="joint_n" params="name type axis_xyz origin_rpy origin_xyz parent child">
    <joint name="${name}" type="${type}">
      <axis xyz="${axis_xyz}" />
      <limit effort="1000.0" lower="-3.14" upper="3.14" velocity="0.5" />
      <origin rpy="${origin_rpy}" xyz="${origin_xyz}" />
      <parent link="${parent}" />
      <child link="${child}" />
    </joint>
  </xacro:macro>

  <xacro:macro name="link_n_cylinder" params="name origin_xyz origin_rpy radius length">
    <link name="${name}">
          <visual>
            <origin rpy="${origin_rpy}" xyz="${origin_xyz}" />
            <geometry>
                <cylinder radius="${radius}" length="${length}" />
            </geometry>
          </visual>
    </link>
  </xacro:macro>

</robot>
```

This is the launch file used for this.

```
   <!-- arg setting -->
   <arg name="model" default="$(find robot_arm_description)/urdf/robot_arm.xacro"/>
   <arg name="gui" default="true"/>
   <arg name="rvizconfig" default="$(find robot_arm_description)/launch/config.rviz"/>
   
   <!-- select model -->
   <param name="robot_description" command="$(find xacro)/xacro $(arg model)"/>
   
   <!-- Combine joint values -->
   <node name="robot_state_publisher" pkg="robot_state_publisher" type="robot_state_publisher"/>
   
   <!-- Show in Rviz -->
   <node name="rviz" pkg="rviz" type="rviz"/>
   
   <!-- send joint values-->
   <node name="joint_state_publisher_gui" pkg="joint_state_publisher_gui" type="joint_state_publisher_gui">
   </node>
   
</launch>
```

Problems arising from robots are invisible in the rviz environment. That is, the interworking of xacro is considered a problem.

If the file is used without interworking, it works normally. As a result, only the base_link is in the macro state as soon as it is linked with the xacro file, this xacro file. What am I doing wrong now?

The example I am referring to now is this.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2lfwBpH-Ty8&t=492s "The Construct"

Help me.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/413303/the-xacro-files-don%27t-seem-to-work-with-each-other.-(ubuntu-20.04-noetic)-r/) by [jaeeunkim](https://answers.ros.org/users/141452/jaeeunkim/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2023-03-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> <link_n_box name="base_link" origin_rpy="0 0 0" origin_xyz="0 0 0" size="1 1 1" />

You are not using the correct synax to create an instance of a macro. The correct way is:

```
<xacro:link_n_box name=... />
```

Edit: I think this syntax change happened quite a few years ago.

---

Originally posted by [Mike Scheutzow](https://answers.ros.org/users/75154/mike-scheutzow/) with karma: 4903 on 2023-03-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jaeeunkim](https://answers.ros.org/users/141452/jaeeunkim/) on 2023-03-12**:
It was a very basic part. Thank you. That was the best answer. Thank you very much.!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!